# Dynamic selection field rails (ajax/ jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have struggled with this problem for a few days, every time when I thought I get the trick, I missed it, so I am asking for your help!
So I have been working on a private tutor centre project where I need to have a dynamic selection box which has values based on a previous selection box. I have followed the tutorial: https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/

For my work:

## Models

### student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :cases
end
```

### case.rb

```
class Case < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :subject
end
```

### category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :cases
   has_many :subjects
end
```

### subject.rb

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :category
   has_many :cases
end
```

## Routes

### routes.rb

```
resources :students do
    resources :cases do
      get 'update_subjects', to: 'cases#update_subjects'
    end
end
```

## Controller

### cases_controller.rb

```
class CasesController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_student, only: [:new]

def index
end

def show
end

def new
  @case = @student.cases.build
  @categories = Category.all
  @subjects = Subject.where("category_id = ?", Category.first.id)
end

def update_subjects 
  @subjects = Subject.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end

private
def case_params....
```

## View

### views/cases/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@student, @case] do |f| %>

.....

<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(@categories.collect { |category| [category.category_name.titleize, category.id]}, 1), {},{ id: 'categories_select' } %>
<%= f.label 'Please select the category' %>

<%= f.select :subject_id, options_for_select(@subjects.collect { |subject|[subject.subject_name.titleize, subject.id]}, 0), {},{ id: 'subjects_select' } %>
<%= f.label 'Please select the subject' %>

....
```

### views/cases/update_subjects.js.erb

```
$("#subjects_select").empty().append("<%=j render(@subjects) %>")
```

### views/subjects/_subject.html.erb

```
<option value="<%= subject.id %>"><%= subject.subject_name.titleize %></option>
```

## AJAX

### assets/javascripts/cases.js.coffee

```
$ ->
$(document).on 'change', '#categories_select', (evt) ->
$.ajax 'update_subjects',
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'script'
  data: {
    category_id: $("#categories_select").val()
  }
  error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
  success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

### assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Rails details

Ruby version = 2.4.1
Rails version = 5.1.1

## Main problem

The ajax did work, but it return **AJAX Error: parsererror** and without any controller errors.
So, I search out about pasererror, and I know the dataType expect a javascript format in return so I checkout my developer tool on safari. From the tool, I can see that there is an XHRs folder whenever I select a option in the category field. and inside that folder I can see a file containing a html file and the most interesting thing is that I think the **update_subjects** method is not working since inside the file, it shows(As I have used debugger inside my code):

`<pre class="debug_dump">--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
category_id: &#39;3&#39; _: &#39;1498731378829&#39;     ===> **I don't know what is this
controller: cases action: show       ===> obvious the action is on case#show student_id: &#39;1&#39; 
id: update_subjects permitted: false </pre>`

and in the terminal:

`Started GET
 "/students/1/cases/update_subjects?category_id=3&_=1498731378829" 
     Processing by CasesController#show as JS
     Parameters: {"category_id"=>"3", "_"=>"1498731378829", "student_id"=>"1", "id"=>"update_subjects"}
     Rendering cases/show.html.erb within layouts/application
     Rendered cases/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
     Student Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
     Rendered students/_nav_after_login.html.erb (0.8ms) [cache miss]
     Completed 200 OK`

Sorry for such a long paragraph, since I want to provide you as much as I can to figure this out. 
I think the main difference between my work and the tutorial is my CASE is based on STUDENT and I don't figure out the routes or something... or maybe I have got typos????
Thanks for your help in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route `get 'update_subjects', to: 'cases#update_subjects'` **is conflicting with the below restful route**

```
/students/:student_id/cases/:id/ case#show
```

So it is routing to the **wrong method**(it should route to `update_subjects` instead)

```
Started GET
"/students/1/cases/update_subjects?category_id=3&_=1498731378829" 
Processing by CasesController#show as JS
Parameters: {"category_id"=>"3", "_"=>"1498731378829", "student_id"=>"1", "id"=>"update_subjects"}
```

which is the reason to your problem.

***Solution:***

Correct your routes!

```
resources :students do
 resources :cases
end
get '/update_subjects', to: 'cases#update_subjects'
```

and use `'/update_subjects'` instead of `'update_subjects'` in the *AJAX* call

Comment: omg! u are my saviour!! haha, I know there is something to do with it, but I just couldn't figure this out.
Can I read it as the ajax path like this situation can be independent of those resources stuff? 
Trying to learn all these routing stuff and ajax and respond_to/wtih

Comment: @StargazerYip I always recommend the *Guides*. Check [*resource-routing-the-rails-default*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) and [*working_with_javascript_in_rails*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Answer (score 0):

your route in ajax call is incorrect.

corrected code:

```
$.ajax '/update_subjects',
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'script'
  data: {
    category_id: $("#categories_select").val()
  }
  error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
  success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

Comment: thx for your information!!...
should have avoid the the reserved word...
trying to get it a new name haha..THX!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the route, you should be using on the ajax call:

```
/students/:student_id/cases/:case_id/update_subjects?...
```

And not:

```
/students/1/cases/update_subjects?...
```

You can execute on the terminal:

```
rake routes
```

And this outputs all available routes.